# http/http traffic analyzer

Tags: c++, http, browser, winpcap

i would like to develop a c++ application that would list all url accessed with its response time within the pc. this probably would be transparent to the user, so it would be a dll.

can anyone gve me some sample codes or tutorials on th said matter.
or any tips and suggestion?!..

thanks alot:))

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/) plug-ins. This is not a trivial exercise. You need to do dependency injection to capture the wininet calls. Even so not all apps use the high level windows api to initiate connections. Applications that make TCP connections might last for a long time since not all TCP calls are simple web requests.

Answer (score 0):

As Byron has said, this is a non-trivial exercise. You could do it using libpcap http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpcap/ having installed http://www.winpcap.org/ on Windows. Tutorials for using libpcap are around and you'd need to learn to filter out everything but http/https traffic, although once you've got to that stage it shouldn't be too hard. Try http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section1.html for starters or http://systhread.net/texts/200805lpcap1.php. Both tutorials look reasonable.

I also feel I should point out that "transparent to the user" and "dll" are not equivalent ideas. A DLL is a set of library functions separate from an application that can be used by many applications - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library. A "standard" executable file (i.e. file ending in .exe) can still be transparent to the user if run, for example, as a Windows Service, which might be more what you are looking for.